# d3 - y-axis with log scale - ticks getting overlapped

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to use log scale for y-axis on my line chart.
Here is my code:

```
 var yScale_for_axis = d3.scaleLog().domain([1,d3.max(vals)]).range ([height,0]);


 g.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale_for_axis).tickFormat( d3.format(".1e"));
```

The ticks are getting overlapped with each other. Heres how it looks:

[image]

What should I do to make it look like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the snippet - it seems to be working. Maybe it's tick formatting which makes ticks overlap:

```js
const width = 400, height = 500;

 // Append SVG 
 const svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

// Create scale
const scale = d3.scaleLog()
                  .domain([1, 5000])
                  .range([20, height - 20]);

// Add scales to axis
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                   .scale(scale);

    //Append group and insert axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr('transform', 'translate(150, 0)')
  .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```